# GraphQL alias top-level data into a nested object

Tags: graphql, schema, graphql-js

Currently I’m querying the `currentUser` for a `city`.

```
query user {
  currentUser {
    city
  }
}
```

However the requirements of my front-end requires the `city` as an object containing `label` and `value`.

```
// this doesn’t work, but is the idea…
query user {
  currentUser {
    city {
      label: city
      value: city
    }
  }
}
```

Is this possible to do at the GraphQL query level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen your database model, but you could have a `City` model, something like:

```
type City {
  id: ID! @unique
  label: String
  value: String
}
```

Then, in your `User` model you could do something like this:

```
type User {
  id: ID! @unique
  .... other User fields
  city: City
}
```

With that schema, you would be able to query the city values inside an user:

```
query user {
  currentUser {
    city {
      label
      value
    }
  }
}
```

You should adapt that to your needs, but that's the main idea that I think you are looking for.